# How to import environmental variables form external file using source

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-ec2, environment-variables

Basically I have a list of environmental variables that I need to set from an external file. Here's what i'm trying to do...

file: /usr/local/env

```
export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=~/.ec2/pk-xxxxx.pem
export EC2_CERT=~/.ec2/cert-xxxxx.pem
export EC2_URL=https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
export EC2_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/ec2
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
```

file: /usr/local/test.sh

```
source /usr/local/env
ec2-describe-instances
```

When i run `/usr/local/test.sh` i get `/bin/ec2-cmd: No such file or directorybe-instances: line 11: /opt/aws/apitools/ec2`

So i check the variables and notice that when:

```
[root@ip-10-244-17-106 ~]# set | grep EC2
EC2_AMITOOL_HOME=/opt/aws/amitools/ec2
EC2_CERT=$'~/.ec2/cert-xxxxx.pem\r'
EC2_HOME=$'/opt/aws/apitools/ec2\r'
EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=$'~/.ec2/pk-xxxxx.pem\r'
```

and when i run:

```
[root@ip-10-244-17-106 ~]# env | grep EC2
EC2_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/ec2
EC2_URL=https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=~/.ec2/pk-xxxxx.pem
EC2_CERT=~/.ec2/cert-xxxxx.pem
```

Why does source wrap $'<variable>\r' around all my values? I think this is why i'm getting the error. Anyone have any help?

Comment: because you created your file on a windows based machine? Try running `dos2unix /usr/local/env` . Good luck.

Comment: Looks like incorrect end-of-line characters. Does your `/usr/local/env` by any chance comes from Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix terminates a line with a Line Feed character, frequently described with the C escaping convention as `\n`.  Windows terminates a line with both a Carriage Return and a Line Feed character, or `\r\n`.  So the actual first line in your sourced file is

`export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=~/.ec2/pk-xxxxx.pem\r\n`

Unix knows to recognize the `\n` as the end-of-line, but thinks that the `\r` is just more of the text from that line.

You can strip that with

`dos2unix /usr/local/env`

Also, some text editors on Windows also offer the option to save with `\n` line termination.

Comment: Thanks, Yes i created the file in windows. I already had the dos2unix command running but the file is actually in a subdirectory and the command wasn't recursively running on subdirectories. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `dos2unix` on your `/usr/local/env`: right now it's using Windows line-endings (carriage-return + line-feed, `\r\n`) instead of Linux ones (just line-feed, `\n`).

Also, something seems to be preventing tilde expansion; I'm not sure what the problem with that is — as far as I can see, the Bash Reference Manual doesn't list *anything* that would turn it off completely — but you can most likely work around it by writing `$HOME` instead of `~`. :-/